# Issue with mod_rewrite in apache

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

This isn't really a problem of mod_rewrite, but mine. I'm pretty sure that my mistake is very stupid, but I can't resolve it.
I set up a very simple XAMPP installation on Mac OS X Lion, with a simple index.php script who does nothing. I'm only trying to learn how to use friendly url in php, so, if I received an url with this format

```
http://localhost/project/controller_name/action_name/id
```

so, if I received this

```
http://localhost/project/user/delete/7
```

can use internally something like this

```
http://localhost/project/index.php?controller=user&action=delete&id=7
```

I created a .httacess on the project folder with this content

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /aletta/index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

I checked if mode_rewrite was enabled and it was. But doesn't work. I type 
`http://localhost/project/user/delete/7` and the page says "Object not found!"

Any help will be greatly appreaciate

Comment: What is your DOCUMENT_ROOT and where do you place .htaccess with above rule?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, `.htaccess` file put in root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    # set project dir to RewriteBase
    RewriteBase /aletta/
    RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+?)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+?)?/([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+?)?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3

</IfModule>
```

and run `http://localhost/user/delete/7`, in `index.php` set `var_dump($_GET);` and result will be:

```
array (size=3)
  'controller' => string 'user' (length=4)
  'action' => string 'delete' (length=6)
  'id' => string '7' (length=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remap */project/$alphanum1/$alphanum2/$numeric* into */project/index.php?controller=$alphanum1&action=$alphanum2&id=$numeric*, then you could give this configuration directives a try:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^project/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /project/index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC]
```